# How to detect user agent of iphone or ipad?

Tags: php, iphone, web-services, user-agent

I am using the following code to parse a remote XML :

```
NSString *urldata=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://url.com/test/a.php"];
NSString *encode=[urldata stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@" urldata %@",urldata);
TBXML *tbxml =[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encode]];
```

And my php script has `$useragent= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ;` . I am unable to determine the user agent. However if call the url from safari ipad or iphone I have the user agent correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `NSMutableURLRequest` in your iPhone code where you can set the user agent. Because it's not being sent to your php webserver as it is not mandatory to send

Comment: Hello this means that i have to change the code in my app, which i dont want because i will have to re upload the app.

Comment: I am afraid that it is the only solution. Maybe you can get the device screen size or other info to determine if it is an iPhone or iPad ?

Comment: You could use 2 different url's, like a.php for the app (because you dont want to resubmit the app) and b.php for the other traffic